# Java custom JComponent: Why is getMinimumSize() ignored?

Tags: java, swing

I've overridden getPreferredSize() and getMinimumSize() in my custom JComponent. While getPreferredSize() is working as expected, getMinimumSize() instead is ignored as I am able to resize the JFrame until my custom component disappears. Why? How to avoid it?

Here is a complete runnable program that shows my point. What am I doing wrong?

**Main.java**

```
    package swing.minimumsize;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class Main extends JFrame {

        public Main() {
            setTitle("Custom Component Test");
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }

        public void display() {
            add(new CustomComponent());
            pack();
            setVisible(true);
        }

        /**
        * @param args
        */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Main main = new Main();
            main.display();
        }

    }
```

**CustomComponent.java**

```
    package swing.minimumsize;

    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Graphics;

    import javax.swing.JComponent;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class CustomComponent extends JComponent {

        @Override
        public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
            return new Dimension(100, 100);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            int margin = 10;
            Dimension dim = getSize();
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(margin, margin, dim.width-margin*2, dim.height-margin*2);
        }

    }
```

Comment: The default layout of `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`, and the default position is `CENTER`.

Comment: Also, consider using `setBorder(BorderFactory.create…)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ..getMinimumSize() instead is ignored as I am able to resize the JFrame until my custom component disappears. Why? How to avoid it?

Check the 1st comment.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public Main() {
        setTitle("Custom Component Test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void display() {
        add(new CustomComponent());
        pack();
        // enforces the minimum size of both frame and component
        setMinimumSize(getSize());
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.display();
    }
}

class CustomComponent extends JComponent {

    CustomComponent() {
        setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        return new Dimension(100, 100);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // paint the BG.
        g.setColor(getBackground());
        g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());

        int margin = 10;
        Dimension dim = getSize();

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(margin, margin, dim.width-margin*2, dim.height-margin*2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I accept this answer because it solves the practical problem. However I also thank Hovercraft Full Of Eels for explaining why my code didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

What is ignored or listened to will depend on the layout of the container that holds the JComponent. Since you're adding your comopnent to a JFrame BorderLayout.CENTER, it makes sense that setMinimumSize would be ignored.

Comment: Based on a suggestion by @camickr, adding `this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.X_AXIS))` and shrinking horizontally will make the minimum size a little easier to see.

Comment: @stivlo: because BorderLayout doesn't use a contained component's minimumSize to determine that component's size.

Comment: ah ok, by definition then, I understand, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The preferred, minimum and maximum sizes are just "suggestions" that the layout manager can use or ignore when laying out components.

Edit:

In addition to Andrew's suggestion you can try using a layout manager that respects the minimum size:

```
    Container contentPane = getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    add(new CustomComponent());
    pack();
    setMinimumSize(getMinimumSize());
    setVisible(true);
```